# changing unity dash icon

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I tried to change the unity dash icon in `/usr/share/unity/icons`. I downloaded a `.png` with the same size and renamed it and copy-pasted to the folder, so I replaced the `launcher_bfb.png` with the new `.png`. I restarted my computer and instead of the new icon, appeared an icon with a question mark instead. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the read permissions on the new icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the permissions of the new icon. Run below command in Terminal

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png
```

Or copy again your icon via this

```
sudo cp /path/to/newIcon.png /usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png
```

This command also sets parent directory permission to new copied file. (logoff/login needs)